# How do I print out a user's input, letter for letter in C?

Tags: c

The assignment has quite a bit of stuff incorporated with it but unfortunately, my Professor is... lacking in explanation.

I'm not quite sure on how the syntax would look if I were to read a user's input, then print out each letter from the input in a vertical line.

In the long-run, the goal is to print out each character from the word in a vertical line, then print out their binary values to the right of them.

Ex:

```
Input = Hello

expected output = 
H
E
L
L
O
```

Comment: I'm not sure the downvotes are necessary. I wouldn't ask the question if I knew how to solve this problem.

Comment: This question is just asking for code. And there are dozens of example code snippets on the web doing exactly this. So this question is not useful and doesn’t show research effort. Hence, I downvoted.

Comment: And whether you know the answer or not is totally irrelevant. You can answer your own question and this question may be interesting or useful, irrespective of if you know how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the keys to programming is breaking problems down into smaller, more manageable pieces. Take it one step at a time, adding one feature each go round.

1. Read the user's input. Don't do anything else, just read it in.
2. Print the user's input exactly as they typed it.

   ```
   Hello
   ```
3. Now print their input character by character. Print `H`, then `e`, then `l`, etc. You'll need to write a loop for this.

   ```
   Hello
   ```

   (The end result will look the same as step #2, but your code will be longer. This is in preparation for the next step.)
4. Now print each character on a separate line instead of all on the same line.

   ```
   H
   e
   l
   l
   o
   ```
5. Finally, convert each letter to uppercase as you print them.

   ```
   H
   E
   L
   L
   O
   ```

If you don't know how to do a particular step, that's where Google comes in. For example:

- [How to loop over a string in C?](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+loop+over+a+string+in+C%3F)
- [How to convert a letter to uppercase in C?](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+convert+a+letter+to+uppercase+in+C%3F)

Answer (score 0):

This would do it; there are other ways of achieving the same result:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    printf("%c\n", c);
```

It does depend a bit on whether you mean 'each letter' or 'each character'.  If it really must be letters, then:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    if (isalpha(c))
        printf("%c\n", c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To traverse a c-style-string (an array of characters terminated by a null character "\0") You could do it in many ways. Here is one:

```
while(*ptr) {
 printf("%c\n", *ptr);
 ptr++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fgets gets a string of  user input.
fputc is one of a few output commands.
Putting the character '\n' causes a new.
Has this helped. if you need a full working listing send an email.